# eclipselink.query-results-cache.ignore-null not caching any result

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I am using EclipseLink 2.5.0
I am trying to achieve following.

- Query an object using non-key filters.
- If result is not null, it should be cached, and future queries with same filter values should not go to data base.
- If no result is found, the result should not be cached and future queries with same filter values should go to data base.

I think, I should be able to achieve it with `eclipselink.query-results-cache.ignore-null` hint, but if I include following

```
<hint name="eclipselink.query-results-cache.ignore-null" value="true"/>
```

No result is being cached.
And if I am including following

```
<hint name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="true"/>
```

Even 'none'(no record found) is being cached.
My complete named query looks like following

```
 <named-query name="find.Employee.findEmployeeByPlace">
        <description>
        Find employee by place.
        </description>
        <query><![CDATA[
        select e 
        from Employee e
        where e.place = :place
        ]]></query>
        <!--<hint name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="true"/>-->
        <hint name="eclipselink.query-results-cache.ignore-null" value="true"/>
    </named-query>
```

My findings seems to be opposite of [How to get Glassfish/EclipseLink/JPA to cache entityManager.find results that return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388692/how-to-get-glassfish-eclipselink-jpa-to-cache-entitymanager-find-results-that-re)

Comment: Just to verify, you are setting both properties right?  eclipselink.query-results-cache.ignore-null will do nothing unless eclipselink.query-results-cache is set to true.  How are you verifying that results are cached?

Comment: @Chris, I am sorry for the late reply. Today I tried to use both properties together. Now, no result is being cached. I can see SQL queries for all three attempts for same set of values. At first, record not found and hence added. At second attempt, record found(Should be added to cache but not being added). At third attempt query is being fired again.

Comment: Please include the code for your transaction, and query execution.  Are you in a dirty transaction?  If so, result may not be cached.